# Running Angular 2 in Centos 7

Tags: node.js, linux, angular, centos, centos7

I am trying to build Angular 2 app in Centos 7 (deploy server) and I am getting the following errors.

I can build the app fine locally on MacOS Sierra. Any idea why I get this error in Centos 7?

Commands:

`npm install`

`npm run build`

`npm start server.js`

[image]

[image]